# Como pegar o valor de um object que esta dentro de um array de objetos> java?

Tags: java, hashmap

Tenho uma lista de boletos no meu GRID e preciso selecionar alguns para mandar imprimir apenas os selecionados , então estou passando como parâmetro lArc_dados(grid) para que eu possa na hora da lógica pegar apenas os que o campo Sel estiver TRUE, porem quando recebo o array de objetos esta me retornando desta forma:

```
{pConvenio=3, pTotal=false, pTitulo=Boletos, ModuloID=23, relIDHuman=boleto756, SUBREPORT_DIR=/appsjava/proj/userfiles/reports/, pDataIni=01/08/2019, pAgrupamento=, pDados=[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], pDataFim=01/09/2019, pFormato=PDF, pOrdem=asc, pFiltros=, pZebrar=false, pInfEspecial=null, pEntidade=1, empresa= EMP1, SessionID=04465432704052428458, relIMGLogoBanco=/appsjava/proj/userfiles/imgs/marca.jpg, relIMGLogo=/appsjava/proj/userfiles/imgs/img.jpg}
```

e sendo assim não consigo acessar o valor de cada objeto dentro de pDados, alguém poderia me dizer como fazer isso ?
Parametros do MXML

```
if (event.detail == Alert.YES)
            {
                var vObj_Param : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
                var vArr_mensagemErro : Array = [];
                var vStr_Filtros : String = "";
                var aBoolHaveErro : Boolean = false;
                vObj_Param.pDataIni = dfDataIni.value;
                vObj_Param.pDataFim = dfDataFim.value;
                vObj_Param.pEntidade = cbEntidade.selectedItem.id;
                vObj_Param.pConvenio = cbConvenios.selectedItem.codigo_006;
                vObj_Param.pDados = lArc_Dados;

                vObj_Param.empresa = cbEntidade.selectedItem.nome;

                Util.retornaParametrosPadraoRel(vObj_Param, ConstantesRelatorios.gCon_ImprimirBoleto756, gCon_TituloRel, "", false, cbFormato.selectedItem.formato,"asc", false);

                Controle.onFechaPopUp();
        }
```

Onde recebe na parte da Logica

```
if (pStr_IDHuman.equals(gCon_ImprimirBoleto756)) {

        //Set<Entry<String, Object>> vHASH_Param =  pHas_Parametros.entrySet();
        Fat_mem_boleto pENT_Boleto = null;
        String vStrAux = "";
        String vCls_Boleto2 = null;
        vCls_Boleto2 = pHas_Parametros.get("pDados").toString();
```

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz o Ajuste no front mesmo MXML e resolvi o problema, segue solução para caso alguém um dia tenha esta duvida.

```
vObj_Param.pDados = "'0'";
for each (var vObj_Dados:Object in lArc_Dados) {
    if(Boolean(vObj_Dados.sel)){
        vObj_Param.pDados = vObj_Param.pDados +",'"+ vObj_Dados.identificador_022 +"'";
    }
}
```